# Add an Eigen's SparseMatrix to an Eigen's Tensor

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, tensor

How can I add an Eigen's SparseMatrix to an Eigen's Tensor?

The following code (which does not compile) explains what I am trying to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

using Eigen::Tensor;
using Eigen::SparseMatrix;

int main()
{
      Tensor<double, 2> tensor(10, 10);

      for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < 10; j++) {
            tensor(i, j) = i * 10 + j;
        }
      }

      SparseMatrix<double> sparse(10, 10);

      auto tensor2 = tensor;
      tensor2 += sparse;
      std::cout << tensor2 << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, this is not implemented.  You have to overload `operator+=` for these two types yourself.  See [this table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) for the correct signature.  See also [»Iterating over the nonzero coefficients « in the Eigen docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html#title2) on how to efficiently iterate over a sparse matrix.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

using Eigen::Tensor;
using Eigen::SparseMatrix;

template < typename T >
Tensor<T,2>& operator+=(Tensor<T,2>& lhs, SparseMatrix<T> const& rhs)
{
  for (int k = 0; k < rhs.outerSize(); ++k)
    for (typename SparseMatrix<T>::InnerIterator it(rhs,k); it; ++it)
      lhs(it.row(), it.col()) = it.value();
  return lhs;
}

int main()
{
      Tensor<double, 2> tensor(10, 10);

      for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < 10; j++) {
            tensor(i, j) = i * 10 + j;
        }
      }

      // We want a sparse matrix that is not only zeros
      Eigen::MatrixXd m = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(10,10);
      m(0,0) = 1;
      SparseMatrix<double> sparse(10, 10);
      sparse = m.sparseView();

      auto tensor2 = tensor;

      tensor2 += sparse;
      std::cout << tensor2 << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in the `+=` method :

```
lhs(it.row(), it.col()) += it.value();
```

and not

```
lhs(it.row(), it.col()) = it.value();
```

?